# is there a data structure equivalent to a non-unique set in python?

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have a very large list of lists of integers which I would like to "hash()" to improve search speed.  The resulting hashed value for each of the nested lists needs to be independent of the order of the integers and only on the values in the list.  This suggested a (frozen) set as a suitable data structure to hash.  However, I need to keep every integer value, whether or not duplicated, which is a show-stopper for sets.

So, that left me ordering the list, converting to a tuple and hashing which is quite slow and I imagine there are better strategies.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to do this more efficiently.

Comment: Why do you need to keep duplicates? And is order important or do you really only need the correct count of each integer?

Comment: Good point, I only need the correct count for each one.  In that case a dictionary of integer:count would seem efficient.  But I don't think dictionaries are hashable.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are hashes.

```
>>> def bag_random(d, n):
...     x = random.randint(0, n)
...     if x in d:
...             d[x] += 1
...     else:
...             d[x] = 1
... 
>>> a = {}
>>> for i in xrange(10**6):
...     bag_random(a, 100)
... 
>>> a
{0: 9856, 1: 9787, 2: 9944, 3: 9822, 4: 9978, 5: 9915, 6: 9915, 7: 9860, 8: 9926, 9: 9756, 10: 9914, 11: 10030, 12: 10009, 13: 9803, 14: 9918, 15: 10136, 16: 9818, 17: 9868, 18: 9893, 19: 9971, 20: 9998, 21: 9982, 22: 9884, 23: 9806, 24: 9998, 25: 9926, 26: 9977, 27: 10011, 28: 10030, 29: 9899, 30: 9808, 31: 9825, 32: 9980, 33: 9812, 34: 9928, 35: 9827, 36: 9934, 37: 9883, 38: 9913, 39: 9893, 40: 9822, 41: 9714, 42: 9871, 43: 9954, 44: 9989, 45: 9694, 46: 9878, 47: 9984, 48: 9893, 49: 9928, 50: 10093, 51: 9881, 52: 9828, 53: 9660, 54: 9884, 55: 9745, 56: 10048, 57: 9845, 58: 9916, 59: 9933, 60: 9944, 61: 9979, 62: 9992, 63: 9635, 64: 9811, 65: 9900, 66: 9950, 67: 9744, 68: 9829, 69: 10037, 70: 9929, 71: 9811, 72: 9830, 73: 10056, 74: 9957, 75: 9992, 76: 9777, 77: 9942, 78: 9809, 79: 9734, 80: 9855, 81: 10021, 82: 9914, 83: 10009, 84: 10018, 85: 9961, 86: 10036, 87: 9849, 88: 9951, 89: 9770, 90: 9795, 91: 9899, 92: 9975, 93: 9935, 94: 10037, 95: 9992, 96: 9868, 97: 10014, 98: 9689, 99: 9883, 100: 9878}
```

Took a second or so on a not wildly fast desktop.

Comment: Yes, this could be a class derived from dictionary and has other efficiencies that could be added. Given the minimal requirements in the question, this is probably clearest.

Comment: You've missed the requirement that the resulting structure needs to be hashed.  Python dict is equivalent to Perl hash, but that doesn't mean you can hash a Python dict!

Comment: Agreed that you can't hash a dict, but can't figure out if that is a requirement or merely a confusion by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is fine, what you need is a way to compute a hash over it that meets your requirements: order of integers doesn't matter, but duplicates need to be respected, and it needs to be fast.

How about computing the product of the numbers?  The resulting number will work well as a hash.  You can keep it within a 32-bit integer if you want to avoid slipping into longs that will slow you down.  The only problem is zeros, but you can skip them, it won't break the hash, only make it less discriminating.

```
LIMIT = 999999937 # largest 9-digit prime
def list_hash(l):
    h = 1
    for i in l:
        if i:
            h *= i
            h %= LIMIT
    return h
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary with the counts. (If your version of python is new enough you can use the Counter class instead. Construct a set out of the items list and hash that

```
counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
for item in items:
     counter[item] += 1
return hash(frozenset(counter.items()))
```

But I don't know that it will be any more efficient that you've already done.

Since this is a hash, it doesn't need to represent the fact that some of your numbers are duplicated. So you could just use:

```
return hash(frozenset(items))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Counter`s as [Winston Ewert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687172/1571593) suggested has other perks. Not only can you naturally have a data structure that you described (`Counter` inherits from `dict` and is therefore hashed), but you can also do some neat stuff, like arithmetic that would probably be useful for your case.

```
from collections import Counter
set1 = Counter("hello")
set2 = Counter("hell")

print(set1)
>> Counter({'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 1})

print(set1)
>> Counter({'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'e': 1})

set1 - set2
>> Counter({'o': 1})
```